# How to implement a double constraint in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design

I am designing a database project that holds records for an alumni association. My goal was to make sure that the names in the awards table only come from those who have been nominated in the alumni table (where `Award_Nominated` acts as a Boolean). I have tried using two booleans, one for nomination and another for winning, but that still leaves a possibility for a logical error, i.e. one can be an award winner without getting nominated. My question is how can I make sure that the award winner names only come from the alumni name values with `Award_nominated` as true.

The relevant tables are declared below:

```
CREATE TABLE Alumni 
(
    Alumni_ID int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
    First_Name varchar(20) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    Last_Name varchar(20) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    Graduation_Year int NOT NULL,
    Course_taken varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    Award_Nominated bit,
    Phone_Number int NOT NULL,
    Email_Address varchar(255) NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY (Alumni_ID, First_Name, Last_Name)
);

CREATE TABLE Awards 
(
    Award_year int NOT NULL,
    Chapters varchar(255),
    Award_Winner_First_Name varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    Award_Winner_Last_Name varchar(20) NOT NULL,

    FOREIGN KEY (Award_Winner_First_Name) REFERENCES Alumni(First_Name),
    FOREIGN KEY (Award_Winner_Last_Name) REFERENCES Alumni(Last_Name),

    Award_purpose varchar(255) NOT NULL
);
```

Comment: Your `Alumni` table has a design problem, because the first and last name columns should not be unique.

Answer (score 4):

Couple points:

- simplify the `Alumni` table's primary key to be **just** the `Alumni_ID`
- Don't make first and last name unique - really bad idea ....
- reference the `Awards` table to the `Alumni` table solely based on the `Alumni_ID` - not on first and last name ....
- don't duplicate the first and last name of the alumni into the `Awards` table -
  if need be, you can get it be a `JOIN` to the `Alumni` table

I'd go with this:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Alumni 
(
    Alumni_ID int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1)
        CONSTRAINT PK_Alumni PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
    First_Name varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    Last_Name varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    Graduation_Year int NOT NULL,
    Course_taken varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    Award_Nominated bit,
    Phone_Number int NOT NULL,
    Email_Address varchar(255) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.Awards 
(
    Award_year int NOT NULL,
    Alumni_ID int NOT NULL 
        CONSTRAINT FK_Award_Alumni REFERENCES dbo.Alumni(Alumni_ID),
    Chapters varchar(255),
    Award_purpose varchar(255) NOT NULL
);
```

Comment: It requires a boolean column ``Winner`` for specify who win the award.

Comment: @SaeedEsmaeelinejad: sorry?? No - if an alumni is referenced from the `Awards` table - he (or she) got this award. It's not a "nominees" table - it's the **Awards** table - awards that have been given to certain alumni ....

Comment: Thanks, but I still don't know how to implement the constraint for the award winners.

Comment: You should ensure (in your application) that only alumni who have been nominated can be stored in the awards table - that's not really easily doable in just database constraints...

Answer (score 2):

Don't duplicate the names in the Awards table. Reference the Alumni ID and join.

```
CREATE TABLE Alumni (
Alumni_ID int  not null identity(1,1),

-- It's possible to have two alumni with the same name.
-- And also to have names longer than 20 characters.
First_Name varchar(255) not null,
Last_Name varchar(255) not null,
Graduation_Year int not null,
Course_taken varchar(255) not null,
Phone_Number int not null,
Email_Address varchar(255) not null,

-- Just the Alumni_ID is sufficient
PRIMARY KEY (Alumni_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE Awards (
Award_year int not null,
Chapters varchar(255),
-- Only reference the ID
Alumni_ID int not null,
FOREIGN key (Alumni_ID) REFERENCES Alumni(Alumni_ID),
Award_purpose varchar(255) not null
);
```

Then join with Alumni to get their names.

```
select First_Name, Last_Name, Awards.*
from Awards
join Alumni on Awards.Alumni_ID = Alumni.Alumni_ID
```